# Xe/Latex get a warning if the document not respect some established rule

Tags: xetex, paragraphs, warnings

Is there a way to get a 'visible' warning if a latex document does not respect some pre-defined rule? For instance, if a paragraph contains more than 7 lines, I still want my document to be compiled, but I want to get a 'visible' warning.

Comment: You might be able to do this in LuaLaTeX with a callback into the paragraph builder.

Comment: By the way, by “visible” do you perhaps mean “visual”?

Comment: @HenriMenke by "visible" I mean "that can be seen easily". To me there is no difference between "visible" and "visual"...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can to do this in LuaLaTeX with the [`post_linebreak_filter` callback](http://wiki.luatex.org/index.php/Post_linebreak_filter).  It will display a warning in the log if the paragraph is more than seven lines long.  Just replace `print` inside the function with `error` to make compilation fail instead of warn.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{luacode}

\begin{luacode*}
local function check_lines (head)
  local lines = 0
  for line in node.traverse_id(node.id("hlist"), head) do
     lines = lines + 1
  end
  if (lines > 7) then
     print("\nWARNING: Paragraph with more than seven lines detected!\n")
  end
  return true
end

luatexbase.add_to_callback("post_linebreak_filter", check_lines, "check_lines", 0)
\end{luacode*}


\begin{document}

\Blindtext

\end{document}
```

---

I don't think such an automated solution as with the Lua callback is possible in other engines.  If you don't mind wrapping every paragraph in an environment you could use `\eatlines` as Vic­tor Ei­jkhout presented in his book [TeX by Topic](https://ctan.org/pkg/texbytopic).  This can even tell you on which line the faulty paragraph occurred.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\newbox\linebox
\newcount\linecount

\def\eatlines{%
  \setbox\linebox\lastbox
  \ifvoid\linebox
  \else
  \unskip\unpenalty
  {\eatlines}%
  \global\advance\linecount by 1
  \box\linebox
  \fi}

\newenvironment{countlinesinpar}{%
  \global\linecount=0
  \vbox\bgroup
}{
  \par\eatlines\egroup
  \ifnum\linecount>7
    \message{^^JWARNING: Paragraph with more than seven lines detected at line \the\inputlineno!^^J}%
  \fi
}

\begin{document}

\begin{countlinesinpar}
\blindtext
\end{countlinesinpar}

\end{document}
```

If you really dislike wrapping every paragraph in an environment you could try sticking the magic in `\everypar`.  Unfortunately, the standard LaTeX documentclasses override `\everypar` at random points (e.g. `\begin{document}`).  So it might be that your document blows up unexpectedly at a random place.  I already noticed that it does not properly handle the indentation box which results in an `Overfull \hbox` warning.  Anyway, place this after `\begin{document}`:

```
\everypar={%
  \global\linecount=0
  \vbox\bgroup\everypar={}%
  \def\par{%
    \endgraf\eatlines\egroup\endgraf
    \ifnum\linecount>7
      \message{^^JWARNING: Paragraph with more than seven lines detected at line \the\inputlineno!^^J}%
    \fi}
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. My current document is in XeTeX (I compile with xeLaTeX). So I am looking for a non Lua solution... Neverthless, I will explore your proposition for my future projects... Thanks

Comment: I will also explore if it is easy to convert a xetex document in lua...

Comment: @S12000 I've updated my answer.

Comment: Hello, thanks a lot again. I accept the solution. I just change the compiler and my document still compiles and the acceptance criteria works...